# iPhone startup orientation (again!)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

EIDT: **fixed**.  It looks like it was a Simulator issue.
Thanks to [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916250/gabriel)

One the simulator I get *only* this:

```
--- UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification -> [<UIDevice: 0x7577d30>] {
```

But on the device I do get a whole raft of new notifications ...

```
--- UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification -> [<UIDevice: 0x1dd5a0c0>] {
--- UIApplicationDidEndResumeAnimationNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x1dd63500>] (null)
--- UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification -> [<UIDevice: 0x1dd5a0c0>] {
--- _UIApplicationDidBeginIgnoringInteractionEventsNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x1dd63500>] (null)
--- UIWindowWillRotateNotification -> [<UIWindow: 0x1e866b40; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1e866ad0>>] {
--- UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x1dd63500>] {
--- UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x1dd63500>] {
--- UIViewAnimationDidCommitNotification -> [UIViewAnimationState] {
--- UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x1dd63500>] {
--- UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x1dd63500>] {
--- UIWindowWillAnimateRotationNotification -> [<UIWindow: 0x1e866b40; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1e866ad0>>] {
--- UIViewAnimationDidCommitNotification -> [UIViewAnimationState] {
--- UIViewAnimationDidStopNotification -> [<UIViewAnimationState: 0x1e8692f0>] {
--- _UIApplicationDidEndIgnoringInteractionEventsNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x1dd63500>] (null)
--- UIWindowDidRotateNotification -> [<UIWindow: 0x1e866b40; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1e866ad0>>] {
--- UIViewAnimationDidStopNotification -> [<UIViewAnimationState: 0x1e867ea0>] {
```

Oh well ...

---

I am really pulling my hair on this one. I have seen many related questions here on a S.O. but couldn't find one that worked for me.

I am using the simplest possible example, Xcode 4.6.2, New Project, Empty Application.

The result is that if the app is started in Portrait, then it can rotate to any of the four supported orientations.

However if it is started in **Landscape**, **it does *not* perform an initial rotate**, *even though rotating the device after launch does honour the four possible rotations.*

Please, note that I have implemented everything that is required for iOS 5 and iOS 6, and that the app **does work in all iOS versions *except* for the initial orientation** which fails everywhere.

Also, please note that I am only after the "plain vanilla" situation *where the device supports all orientation* and the should work "out of the box" (except that it doesn't!)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface TestUIVIew: UIView
@end
@implementation TestUIVIew
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect {
    CGContextRef context = ::UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ;
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds ;
    CGMutablePathRef  p = ::CGPathCreateMutable() ;

    CGFloat minx = ::CGRectGetMinX(bounds) ;
    CGFloat miny = ::CGRectGetMinY(bounds) ;
    CGFloat maxx = ::CGRectGetMaxX(bounds) ;
    CGFloat maxy = ::CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) ;

    CGPoint TL = (CGPoint) {minx, miny} ;
    CGPoint BL = (CGPoint) {minx, maxy} ;
    CGPoint TR = (CGPoint) {maxx, miny} ;
    CGPoint BR = (CGPoint) {maxx, maxy} ;

    ::CGPathMoveToPoint     (p, 0, TL.x, TL.y) ;
    ::CGPathAddLineToPoint  (p, 0, BR.x, BR.y) ;
    ::CGPathMoveToPoint     (p, 0, TR.x, TR.y) ;
    ::CGPathAddLineToPoint  (p, 0, BL.x, BL.y) ;

    ::CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0f) ;
    ::CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor) ;
    ::CGContextAddPath(context, p) ;

    ::CGContextStrokePath(context) ;
    ::CGPathRelease(p) ;
}
@end

@interface SimplestViewController : UIViewController
@end
@implementation SimplestViewController
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    return YES ;
}
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll ;
}
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES ;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController * vc = [SimplestViewController new] ;
    vc.view = [TestUIVIew new] ;
    self.window.rootViewController = vc ;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
@end
```

I've tried with every variant of the simulator 5.0, 5.1, 6.0 & 6.1 with the exact same outcome:
It seems that I just do not get any rotation message or if I do, it is not honoured.

So, I added this in main:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define S(x)    #x
#define str(x)  case x: return @S(x)

static NSString * devO(UIDeviceOrientation o) {
    switch (o) {
            str(UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) ;
            str(UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) ;
            str(UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ;
            str(UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ;
            str(UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) ;
            str(UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp) ;
            str(UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) ;

        default:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"??? UIDeviceOrientation<%08.8x> ???", o] ;
    }
}

static NSString *  intfO(UIInterfaceOrientation o) {
    switch (o) {
            str(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ;
            str(UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ;
            str(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ;
            str(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ;

        default:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"??? UIInterfaceOrientation<%08.8x> ???", o] ;
    }
}

static void (^notifHandler)(NSNotification *) = ^(NSNotification *note) {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientO = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation ;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientI = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    ::NSLog(@"!   NOTE   !  [device:%@--app:%@]\n--- %@ -> [%@] %@"
            , devO(orientO)
            , intfO(orientI)
            , note.name
            , note.object
            , note.userInfo) ;
} ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications] ;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName: nil
                                                          object: nil
                                                           queue: nil
                                                      usingBlock: notifHandler] ;

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, ::NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

And here's the log:

```
2013-04-26 17:43:06.429 AutoRotate[82160:1a03] !   NOTE   !      [device:UIDeviceOrientationUnknown--app:??? UIInterfaceOrientation<00000000> ???]
--- kBKSDisplayServerDiedNotification -> [(null)] (null)
2013-04-26 17:43:06.489 AutoRotate[82160:2b03] !   NOTE   !      [device:UIDeviceOrientationUnknown--app:??? UIInterfaceOrientation<00000000> ???]
--- NSWillBecomeMultiThreadedNotification -> [(null)] (null)
2013-04-26 17:43:06.523 AutoRotate[82160:c07] !   NOTE   !      [device:UIDeviceOrientationUnknown--app:??? UIInterfaceOrientation<00000000> ???]
--- _UIWindowDidCreateWindowContextNotification -> [<UIStatusBarWindow: 0x9667540; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x96674a0>>] {
    "_UIWindowContextIDKey" = "-1367435195";
}
[...]
2013-04-26 17:43:06.659 AutoRotate[82160:1a03] !   NOTE   !      [device:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait--app:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
--- kBKSHIDServerDiedNotification -> [(null)] (null)
2013-04-26 17:43:06.662 AutoRotate[82160:c07] !   NOTE   !      [device:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait--app:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
--- UIApplicationDidEndResumeAnimationNotification -> [<UIApplication: 0x7580b80>] (null)
2013-04-26 17:43:06.663 AutoRotate[82160:c07] !   NOTE   !      [device:UIDeviceOrientationUnknown--app:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
--- UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification -> [<UIDevice: 0x7577d30>] {
    UIDeviceOrientationRotateAnimatedUserInfoKey = 1;
}
```

Notice the last line?

[image: Here's a screen shot]

As you can see a rotation notification is indeed sent ... but has no effect?
What gives?

Puzzled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on a real device instead of the simulator.

Comment: It works on the device! I knew of some of the Simulator limitations, ... I guess you just found out a new one. Thanks!